# How do I configure AutoFac to inject IPrincipal into custom DbContext on each ApiRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, autofac, unit-of-work

We are developing a website that uses the repository pattern/unit of work approach. We use Autofac to assist with the construction of objects between these tiers of abstraction.

I've written an AutoFac authentication filter that currently grabs Basic Auth headers and creates an IPrincipal object and assigns it to  HttpContext.Current.User

In our custom DbContext class I want Autofac to get a copy of this IPrinipal object without having to look into System.Web.HttpContext (in an effort to keep this decoupled)

Does anyone have any hints on how I can get AutoFac to grab this IPrincipal and inject it into
my custom DbContext class on each Web API call?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I tried... 

builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).As<IPrincipal>().InstancePerApiRequest();


but my DbContext class gets created my before WebApiAuthenticationFilter gets a chance to set HttpContext.Current.User

Comment: The question becomes how to ensure that AutoFac creates my DbContext AFTER I've had a chance to inject the current IPrincipal

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm struggling with this same issue. I just want to inject the claims of the  httpcontext.current.User.Identity, but your way would work to.

Comment: Dose it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584471/538387