# EntityFrameworkCore - How to inject IPrincipal when DbContextPool is enabled

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I have an aspnet core MVC application, and I need to inject the `IPrincipal` of the current request so that I know who is the current logged in user. I followed [this](http://davidpine.net/blog/principal-architecture-changes/) article with no problem.

Now I need the `IPrincipal` in my `Dbcontext` to auto-populate audit fields (CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, etc). Being naive I could inject the `IPrincipal` in my `DbContext` constructor:

```
public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options, IPrincipal principal)
```

But I am using the `DBContextPool`, which reuses `DbContext` instances across WebAPI requests.

What's the proper way to inject `IPrincipal` in this scenario?

------------------- Update ----------------------

I am thinking I can follow the same approach as the [HttpContextAccesor](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/87cd79d6fc54bb4abf07c1e380cd7a9498a78612/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpContextAccessor.cs), and create a `IClaimsPrincipalAccessor`, register it as a singleton and inject it into my `Dbcontext`.

For asp net core applications I need an `HttpContextClaimsPrincipalAccesor`, where `ClaimsPrincipal` comes from the `HttpContext.User`

Answer (score 2):

You can register the [`IPrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) as a Transient service on your Startup, like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(provider => 
                provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
    // ...
}
```

Then on your DbContext constructor you can inject the [`IServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) that will allow you to get the current `IPrincipal` instance, for example:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    private IServiceProvider _services;
    public YourDbContext(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var principal = _services.GetService<IPrincipal>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why `ClaimsPrincipal` doesn't have an interface? The type of `HttpContext.User` **is** a `ClaimsPrincipal` and not an `IPrincipal`. So doing it your way (which I fully agree is the right way) is confusing me since I need to also read claims and casting what you have here as `principal` to `ClaimsPrincipal` is guaranteed to work at runtime - but is very unfriendly for unit tests since I can't mock `IClaimsPrincipal`. Just odd :-/

Comment: This solution won't work because as the original question stated, using pooling requires there to be a public constructor which only takes the DbContextOptions. Adding the second parameter causes an exception. I came here looking for the same answer after trying what the OP has done.

Comment: @MikeG In that case I think the only way would be to do it on an intermediate layer (data access layer, ...), not inside the DbContext. Actually gathering that information doesn't seems to be a responsibility of a DbContext.